# Warning: No deployer available in JDeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I couldn't find any info in google on this one, someone changed properties on a project and I'm not sure why the project can no longer deploy to jar. It compiles ok, but won't build into a jar file even though the dependencies do so just fine.

Has anyone run into this issue in JDeveloper before?

I can rename the jar to a different name (it's a dependency as well) but I need that specific name to match up with the other project.

I'm working with JDeveloper 10g and the project has been building fine for the last few months, and just now I'm getting this error which I can find no source or help on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it, it plagued me for 3 days.

The project itself had some deploy profile stuck in it, directly in the properties file of the project, not the external "blah blah.deploy".

When looking under the "Miscellaneous Files" area I noticed an extra deploy file, i.e. two deploy files in that area even though I hadn't deployed yet. This is how I figured out it was stuck in the project properties not in the external files. Removing one of these from the project fixed the issue, although I imagine ridding the project of both and creating a new deploy profile (still need to do this) would also fix it.

10g for the lose :p